# React - React router dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

Today I worked with React and also with react-router-dom. I wanted to create my own "Route" using my own class, but I can't figure out how to get the id before rendering the page.

My code is as follows:

```
import React from "react"
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
import { useAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext"

export default function ServerRoute({ component: Component, ...rest }) {

    const { currentUser } = useAuth();

    return(
        <Route {...rest} render={props => {
            return currentUser ? /* Do stuff */ <Component {...props}/> : <Redirect to="/auth/login"/>
        }}/>
    )

}
```

My index is as follows:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { AuthProvider } from '../contexts/AuthContext';
import ServerRoute from './ServerRoute';

const TruRouter = () => {

    return(
        <AuthProvider>
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <ServerRoute path="/server/:id" component={Component}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </AuthProvider>
    )

}

export default TruRouter;
```

And I wonder how I get the item in the "ServerRoute" - :id, is it somehow possible, if so, how please?

Thanks you very much, Domi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [react-router-dom documentation](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/render-func), "The render prop function has access to all the same route props (match, location and history) as the component render prop."

This means that for your example in the `render` method of the `Router` component, you should have access to the params through `props.match.params`.

For your case:

```js
// rest of the code above

    return(
        <Route {...rest} render={props => {
            const id = props.match.params.id // get the current route id

            return currentUser ? /* Do stuff */ <Component {...props}/> : <Redirect to="/auth/login"/>
        }}/>
    )
```